# "Update-Database" command fails with TimeOut exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, timeout, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF migrations and have a table with a lot of data. I need to change MaxLength of a concrete column (it hadn't length constraints).

```
ALTER TABLE MyDb ALTER COLUMN [MyColumn] [nvarchar](2) NULL
```

And this command fails with TimeOut exception.
Tried to setup CommandTimeout i nDbContext constructor without any luck.

Is there any way to disable or setup timeout for Package Manager Console EF commands?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found solution by myself.

Since EF5 there is a new property *CommandTimeout* which is available from *DbMigrationsConfiguration*

```
internal sealed class MyMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        CommandTimeout = 10000; // migration timeout
    }
}
```

Comment: What calls the Configuration method in that example? Or is that supposed to be a constructor method (and in the example it inadvertently doesn't match the class name)?

Comment: try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer or this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: just a side note: A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely). (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 35):

Alternatively script out the change by using

```
Update-Database -script
```

You can then take the script and run it using SQL Management Studio against the database.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I didn't realize you could do this. :-)

Comment: To where is the script generated?  I tried this, but didn't get a script.  Does it save it as a file someplace?

Comment: Hey, It's been a while since I've used this, but I am fairly sure it dumped it into the console?

Comment: In VS 2017 it opened up a new file with sql commands, great tip.

Comment: For those who are curious, the migration is technically `applied` at this point too. No further action is required, so it is on you to ensure the SQL is actually executed - if you don't execute the SQL EF will merrily continue on as if you have

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this same Update-Database command timeout issue with EntityFrameworkCore. Found that the -script argument no longer exists in EFCore. Documentation says you need to use Script-Migration.

[EFCore Script-Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#script-migration)

You specify the last migration that was applied to your database and it will generate a script for everything after it to get it current:

```
Script-Migration 20210307058985_addIndexesToClientTable
```

You can get the full migration id from your migration file names in your .net project, just take the .cs off the end. Alternatively, you can get it from your __EFMigrationsHistory table in your database.

If you need a script for creating a new DB it says to use 0:

```
Script-Migration 0 InitialCreate
```

For me it opened a temp .sql file in VS since I ran it from the package console manager and I was able to then copy and execute it in MSSQL Management Studio.

**8/20/21 Update**

for some reason my new migrations are requiring me to provide the optional -From and -To switches in order for it to generate a script:

Script-Migration -From 20210307058985_addIndexesToClientTable -To 20210820205751_modifyIndexesOnClientTable

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something different but I was able to use the script command in VS17.3.5 (which took 16 minutes to run on SSMS!). `update-database -script`

Comment: Even the Script-Migration command is giving me the "Connect Timeout expired" error message.

Comment: How can I generate a script for Remove-Migration?

Answer (score 2):

I just had almost the exact same thing: timeout expired when trying to increase a column length.  For me, using `update-database` had been working just fine an hour ago.  The problem turned out to be an open transaction on the database and table I was trying to alter.  Once I rolled back that transaction, the `update-database` command went through without problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by a very large query which timed out in EF but was able to complete in SSMS.

The answer which suggests `Update-Database -script` did not work for me, it gave another error message.

For me, I did the following:

- Open SSMS
- Tools > SQL Server Profiler
- Go back to VS and run Update-Database
- Watch the Server Profiler
- You should be able to see the query it times out on
- Copy that query and run it in SSMS
- Now re-run Update-Database and that slower part should be fine because the query has already been completed.

Disclaimer: This might not work for all cases, because it depends on what particular query is slowing you down. For me, it worked.

Comment: this way is not work in .net 5.

Comment: @AliRasouli this is framework agnostic, it relies on using SQL Server Profiler

Answer (score 0):

Just add in ConnectionStrings "Command Timeout=120" for MySql 120sec for example

Comment: this way is not work in .net 5.

Answer (score 0):

@deeptowncitizen's answer is definitely an easy way to accomplish this. I wanted to offer another simple way as well.

If you have your migration host setup (E.G. what is known as the `-StartupProject` in the `Update-Database` command. You can setup your DI registration as follows

```
services.AddDbContext<MarketDataContext, MarketDataContext>(opts =>
            {
                opts
                    .UseSqlServer(dbConn, a => 
                        a.MigrationsAssembly("xxxxxx.Database.MarketData")
                            .CommandTimeout(10000)) //set the timeout here
                    .EnableDetailedErrors()
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            });
```

This works great in my situation because this context is nugetized and I don't want consumers to automatically have a command timeout of 10000. I only want this ridiculously high timeout to take effect during my build / release pipeline

Comment: this way is not work in .net 5.

Comment: @AliRasouli this does work in .NET 5 onwards.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that this technique causes the commandtimeout to be set when the application runs, not just for migrations.

At first glance it looks like `CommandTimeout` acting on the `MigrationsAssembly`. But the method is being called on the dbContextOptionsBuilder  that is returned from the `MigrationsAssembly`. So the parameter `a` in the above example

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem, but it was fixed by using `CommandTimeout=9024`

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=5432;database=DB_NAME;userid=USER_NAME;password=PASSWORD;CommandTimeout=9024;"
```

here is the output of `update-database`

[image]