# "Update-Database" times out while Running Seed Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a mountain of seed data that gets populated when a data-base is initially created.  When running the `update-database` command, I get past all of the table creation just fine, but when it hits the `Running Seed method` portion, I eventually get this:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330603/update-database-command-fails-with-timeout-exception) which looked promising.  I tried using `CommandTimeout`, but the results were the same.

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    CommandTimeout = 0; // A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).
}
```

I also tried putting in inside the seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    CommandTimeout = 0;
    /// all the rest of the seed stuff
}
```

Still got the timeout error.

I then tried this:

```
update-database -script
```

But... nothing happened?  Or, is the script file saved someplace?  I expected a script full of insert commands, but didn't get one.  Or, does the script only generate if there is table creation and modification to be done?  (which there isn't, as that portion executed just fine on an earlier attempt.)